# React-Bootstrap and styled components with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I would like to know if is there a way to use styled-components + React JS + Typescript + Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, there is and everything is working properly. There are types for styled-components.